# Flutter custom font multi weight doesn't work properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use a family font with multi weight in a flutter. But when I use font style with weight **bold (w700)** and **heavy(w800)**, it doesn't work. Only work until **semibold/medium (w600)**

Here is my font assets folder structure :

```
myapp\assets\fonts\unisans\unisans_Bold.ttf
myapp\assets\fonts\unisans\unisans_Heavy.ttf
myapp\assets\fonts\unisans\unisans_Reguler.ttf
myapp\assets\fonts\unisans\unisans_Semibold.ttf
```

Defined fonts in pubspec.yaml :

```
 fonts:
    - family: Unisans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/unisans/unisans_Reguler.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/unisans/unisans_Semibold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/unisans/unisans_Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/unisans/unisans_Heavy.ttf
          weight: 800
```

And call them in flutter like this :

```
Text(
  "Halo",
  style: TextStyle(
     color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
     fontFamily: "Unisans",
     fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
     fontSize: 30),
)
```

I also tried FontWeight.w700, but still didn't applied. It is only work with **reguler** and **w600** style.

Does flutter cannot work with multi weight of fonts or it depends on the fonts?

Comment: Really strange, everything looks fine in your code. Try to remove from every asset the weight property, and make a test widget with every FontWeight and try to understand the differences, after that try to set the weight property to every asset and check what is changed.

Comment: I suddenly found the problem. Very trivial problem. This is because each font has different "Font Name". 
For example:  
Unisans-Bold has Font Name (UnisansBold) Instead of Unisans. Unisans-Heavy has Font Name (UnisansHeavy) instead of Unisans. 

In flutter, to make the weight style works, all of the font files must have same Font Name. I check the font name when open the font file in the windows OS.

But I'm still curious why flutter consider it even when we declared it on pubspec.yaml .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suddenly found the problem. Very trivial problem. This is because each font has different "Font Name". For example: Unisans-Bold has Font Name (UnisansBold) Instead of Unisans. Unisans-Heavy has Font Name (UnisansHeavy) instead of Unisans. In flutter, to make the weight style works, all of the font files must have same Font Name. I check the font name when open the font file in the windows OS. But I'm still curious why flutter consider it even when we declared it on pubspec.yaml .

Comment: Are you sure about the file names having to follow the same naming structure? Pls share a link to the docs that explains this (I am not able to find anything related to the file name naming convention)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't find any docs too. This based on my experience after exploration