# Flutter Font Management

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I recently got over this odd behavior in Flutter, someone else here on stack-overflow pointed it out but never posted an full fix or workaround, seems flutter font management is a bit odd or I am missing something, I have defined this in my pubspec.yaml:

```
fonts:
- family: OpenSans
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
      weight: 400
    - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
      style: italic
    - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
      weight: 300
    - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf
      weight: 600
    - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
    - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
      weight: 800
```

Now for the last week I noticed in the app all my custom font styles looked off etc but today it became quite obvious the weights did not work correctly and eventually someone pointed out that the font files have different names thus flutter does not really use OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf for soemthing like
`fontFamily:'OpenSans', fontWeight: FontWeight.w600` instead I have to do something like this to see the right font file used : `headline6: TextStyle(fontFamily:'OpenSans SemiBold',fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontSize: 18,color: Color(0xFF2E64B0))`

My question is how to fix this so I can set a single fontFamily and use weights instead of the current way that seems really odd and cumbersome. Or maybe am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: `fontFamily` should be `'OpenSans'` because you have defined `family` in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Indeed , that is the expected behavior , but not the one I seem to get. This is the post that helped me understand what my issue is but has no solution to making a font family usable the easy/lazy way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252792/flutter-custom-font-multi-weight-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: You can use [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/) to edit the name of the fonts in the TTF files. This way you can rename all of them to OpenSans and make it work with Flutter.

Comment: Thank you , I will try this as a workaround .